# Multi-geo in Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, graph, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

Does using Multi-geo causes any changes in the graph API ?
How can I get a site from a tenant(Multi-Geo enabled Tenant)using Graph API?

Is Using Multi-Geo causes any changes in the site Data, User Data ..and so on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the document:

[image]

Create and delete site collections and set tenant site collection properties: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/multigeo-sampleapplicationsetup#create-and-delete-site-collections-and-set-tenant-site-collection-properties

Hope this helps.